# How to know when a file opened with ACTION_VIEW is closed

Tags: android, file

I am opening a file using the ACTION_VIEW intent from my app. 
Now i want to perform some actions in my app whenever this file is closed.

This can be closed either by pressing back or by the context menu option of the app that opened the file.

Is there a way my app can get to know when a file is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you want to launch the other app, use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`. And override the `onActivityResult()` method in your activity class. Most of the apps return a result of `RESULT_OK` or `RESULT_CANCELED` when the user exits from their app. And when they exit, `onActivityResult()` method will be called in your app, where you can put code to do whatever you want after that. Check the [android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for more help and info

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but what i see onactivityResult is getting invoked soon after the file is opened, not when it is closed.

Comment: I was setting the flag NEW_TASK while launching the intent. Thats why i was getting the result immediately